# Showing div with info while hovering a table does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a tal template that draws a table, but the function that shows a cell header when hovering doesn't work.

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <div class="container"><input class="form-control" id="multi_host_filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter"></div>
        <div class="container" tal:repeat="machine_result item.items()">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block btn-expand" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#${machine_result[0]}_div" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="${machine_result[0]}_div" tal:content="machine_result[0]"/>
        <div class="collapse container" id="${machine_result[0]}_div">
          <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-responsive table-bordered">
            <tr tal:repeat="tuple machine_result[1].get('return')">
              <th tal:condition="repeat['tuple'].index==0" tal:repeat="data tuple.split(';;')" tal:content="data"/>
              <td class="td-hover" tal:condition="repeat['tuple'].index!=0" tal:repeat="data tuple.split(';;')" tal:content="data"/>
            </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>


     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#multi_host_filter").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("table tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });



    $("td").on({
       mouseenter: function(e){
            var $cell = $(this);
            var headerVal = $cell.closest("table").find("tr > th").eq($cell.index()).html();
            var paragraph = '<p>' + headerVal + '</p>';
            $('#floating_div').html(paragraph);
            $('#floating-div').stop(true);
            $('#floating_div').css({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
            $('#floating_div').width(150);
            $('#floating_div').css('z-index', 4000);
            $('#floating_div').height(40);
        },
        mouseleave: function(e){
            $('#floating_div').css('z-index', -4000);
            $('#floating-div').css('display', 'none');
        },
    });
    
    
    </script>
```

I have already tried $('table').hover(function(){//something}
, function(){//something when leave}) but div is not hidden when i leave table

"#floating-div" is already created at index.html, and i can modify it from this script
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking over your code, for the most part it seems to be exactly what you are trying to accomplish -- the table was a bit wonky in how it was formatted ( open and close THs and TDs `<th>...</th>` and `<td>...</td>` -- but I'm also not familiar with tal templates ).

But reducing your code to the minimums and reusing a lot of it, I generated the below solution.

The only other real edit is that I added in a `mouseleave()` event on the `#floating_div`, populating the div immediately underneath the cursor can cause cursor-confusion.  Where it thought it was sitting on top of a `<td>` it is now suddenly sitting on top of a `#floating_div`.  So, "leaving" the `<td>` doesn't work.  This is because the cursor is now on top of something else and will leave that.

```js
$("td").on({
   mouseenter: function(e){
        //console.log( 'in',  this );
        let output = $(this).closest("table").find("tr > th").eq($(this).index()).html();
        $('#floating_div').html( output );
        $('#floating_div').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#floating_div').css({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
    },
    mouseleave: function(e){
        //console.log( 'out', this );
        $('#floating_div').addClass('hidden');
    },
});

$('#floating_div').mouseleave( function(){
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
table, td, th{ padding: 5px; border: solid 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
#floating_div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
}
  #floating_div.hidden{
    display: none;
    top: -1000px;
    left: -1000px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="floating_div" class="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: It seems to work when i prompt variable 'output', but now when i hover over a td, #floating_div does not show. May it be because of the template?

Comment: possibly, you can try duplicating the code that shows #floating_div , in a separate function (maybe provide some dummy input and top/left coordinates) -- then in the the web developer tools, check out the styles that have been applied to #floating_div

Comment: ... and if its still acting wonky, it may be worth the time to do a line-by-line review of the #floating_div show controls (you can add in console.log()s to see if it's stopping prematurely or delete all the lines and gradually add them back in to see if something is mis-behaving)

Comment: Reviewing code line by line I found out CSS is not hiding #floating-div, I guess I'll change my function and show the info into a non-hidable div. Thank you for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: Instead of hiding it, changing its "left" property to a very high value works